# Rotation Matrix Sign Convention

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I have two methods of computing a rotation matrix. One gives me the following matrix:

$$
R_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.29320837 & 0.89709592 & -0.33052649 \\
    -0.85529364 & 0.40061608 & 0.32860241 \\
    0.42720211 & 0.18634823 & 0.88474442 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The other results in:

$$
R_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -0.29320837 & -0.89709592 & -0.33052649 \\
    0.85529364 & -0.40061608 & 0.32860241 \\
    -0.42720211 & -0.18634823 & 0.88474442 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The difference is in the signs of the first two columns. Ultimately, I need to calculate the corresponding quaternion for each matrix, which end up not being the same:

$$
\begin{align}
q_1 &= [0.80289614, -0.04429408, -0.23593606, -0.5456464] \\
q_2 &= [0.5456464 , -0.23593606,  0.04429408,  0.80289614]
\end{align}
$$

The question is: how can I enforce the signs of the first two columns so that I get consistent matrices regardless of the method I use? More specifically, I want the final outcome to follow the sign convention of $R_1$ and not $R_2$. But if I obtain a matrix following the sign convention of $R_2$, I want to detect that it's not following the sign convention of $R_1$, and make necessary changes.

Comment: What's the method?  Otherwise this seems impossible to answer.

Comment: Mmm... I was hoping it wouldn't require a lot of details. But let's see. :) The area is camera calibration for robotics. The rotation matrix is part of camera extrinsic parameters. Method 1 is the [solvePnP](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga549c2075fac14829ff4a58bc931c033d) function in OpenCV. Method 2 is my implementation of the same function. To obtain a valid rotation matrix, a constraint is enforced such that $R^T R = I$ (I use the squared Frobenius norm in my implementation). In the end, both methods converge to the same matrix, but some signs are different.

Comment: I should add that, sometimes (maybe by accident), Method 2 converges to the same matrix as Method 1 (all signs match). I don't think I have to add a constraint in my optimization model to enforce signs. I could just post-process the matrix and check for some conditions. That's what I'm trying to figure out. Should I check the Euler angles? Or something else?

Comment: I wouldn’t call these “the same matrix” with some different signs. They represent rather different rotations. Relative to $R_1$, $R_2$ includes a 180-degree rotation about the $z$-axis. This suggests to me that the two methods disagree on which way is “up” relative to the plane of rotation.

Comment: Yes! I also suspect a direction difference. How do I detect that ($z$-axis direction) for a given rotation matrix?

Comment: I think I got it. Method 1 seems to always give me a negative Euler angle for the $z$ axis. So I just have to flip the signs of the first two columns of the rotation matrix obtained by Method 2 if its Euler angle about $z$ is positive. I also have to flip the sign of the associated translation vector.